# How to calculate time difference in between same rows step by step continously in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, time

Here I have a dataset with three inputs x1,x2,x3 with date and time. Here in my X3 column I have similar values in rows.

What I want to do is I want to find the time difference in similar values step wise in rows  when the start time will be 0.

Here I used the code

```
df['time_diff']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + " " + df['time'],
                            format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', dayfirst=True)

mask = df['x3'].ne(0)
df['Duration'] = df[mask].groupby(['date','x3'])['time_diff'].transform('first')
df['Duration'] = df['time_diff'].sub(df['Duration']).dt.total_seconds().div(3600)
```

This code is giving this value.

```html
date time                 x3         Expected output of time difference
10/3/2018 6:00:00         0          NaN
10/3/2018 7:00:00         5          0 =start time for 5
10/3/2018 8:00:00         0          NaN
10/3/2018 9:00:00         7          0=start time for 7
10/3/2018 10:00:00 0          NaN
10/3/2018 11:00:00 0          NaN
10/3/2018 12:00:00 0          NaN
10/3/2018 13:45:00 0          NaN
10/3/2018 15:00:00 0          NaN
10/3/2018 16:00:00 0          NaN
10/3/2018 17:00:00 0          NaN
10/3/2018 18:00:00 0          NaN
10/3/2018 19:00:00 5          12 hr =from starting time of 5
10/3/2018 20:00:00 0          NaN
10/3/2018 21:30:00 7          12.30hr = from starting time of 7
10/4/2018 6:00:00         0         NaN
10/4/2018 7:00:00         0         NaN
10/4/2018 8:00:00         5         0 = starting time of 5 because new day
10/4/2018 9:00:00         7         0 = starting time of 5 because new day
10/4/2018 11:00:00 5         3hr
10/4/2018 12:00:00 5         4hr
10/4/2018 13:00:00 5         5hr
10/4/2018 16:00:00 0         NaN
10/4/2018 17:00:00 0         NaN
10/4/2018 18:00:00 7         11hr
```

But what I expected output is I want to find the time difference step wise with time mean:

```html
date time       x3   Expected for 5 (time_diff) Expected for 7(time_diff) 
10/3/2018 6:00:00     0      NaN                      NaN
10/3/2018 7:00:00     5      0 =start time for 5      NaN
10/3/2018 8:00:00     0      1hr                      NaN
10/3/2018 9:00:00     7      1hr                      0=start time for 7                          
10/3/2018 11:00:00    0      1hr                      1hr
10/3/2018 12:00:00    0      1hr                      1hr
10/3/2018 13:45:00    0      1.45hr                   1.45hr
10/3/2018 15:00:00    0      1.15hr                   1.15hr
10/3/2018 16:00:00    0      1hr                      1hr
10/3/2018 17:00:00    0      1hr                      1hr
10/3/2018 18:00:00    0      1hr                      1hr
10/3/2018 19:00:00    5     0 hr =nextstartingtime5   1hr
10/3/2018 20:00:00    0      1hr                       1hr
10/3/2018 21:30:00    7      1.5hr                    0 =starting 7
10/4/2018 6:00:00     0      1hr                       1hr
10/4/2018 7:00:00     0      1hr                       1hr
10/4/2018 8:00:00     5      0 = startingbecausenewda  1hr
10/4/2018 9:00:00     7      1hr                       0 =starting time for 7
10/4/2018 11:00:00    5      2hr                      2hr
10/4/2018 12:00:00    5      1hr                      1hr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can processing all unique values without `0` in `x3` column:

```
df['time_diff']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + " " + df['time'],
                            format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', dayfirst=True)

for x in df.loc[df['x3'].ne(0), 'x3'].unique():
    s = df['x3'].eq(x).cumsum()
    df['Expected {}'.format(x)] = (df[s != 0].groupby(['date',s])['time_diff']
                                                .diff()
                                                .dt.total_seconds()
                                                .div(3600)
                                                .fillna(0))
```

---

```
print (df)
         date      time  x3 Expected           time_diff  Expected 5  \
0   10/3/2018   6:00:00   0      NaN 2018-03-10 06:00:00         NaN   
1   10/3/2018   7:00:00   5        0 2018-03-10 07:00:00        0.00   
2   10/3/2018   8:00:00   0      NaN 2018-03-10 08:00:00        1.00   
3   10/3/2018   9:00:00   7        0 2018-03-10 09:00:00        1.00   
4   10/3/2018  10:00:00   0      NaN 2018-03-10 10:00:00        1.00   
5   10/3/2018  11:00:00   0      NaN 2018-03-10 11:00:00        1.00   
6   10/3/2018  12:00:00   0      NaN 2018-03-10 12:00:00        1.00   
7   10/3/2018  13:45:00   0      NaN 2018-03-10 13:45:00        1.75   
8   10/3/2018  15:00:00   0      NaN 2018-03-10 15:00:00        1.25   
9   10/3/2018  16:00:00   0      NaN 2018-03-10 16:00:00        1.00   
10  10/3/2018  17:00:00   0      NaN 2018-03-10 17:00:00        1.00   
11  10/3/2018  18:00:00   0      NaN 2018-03-10 18:00:00        1.00   
12  10/3/2018  19:00:00   5     12hr 2018-03-10 19:00:00        0.00   
13  10/3/2018  20:00:00   0      NaN 2018-03-10 20:00:00        1.00   
14  10/3/2018  21:30:00   7  12.30hr 2018-03-10 21:30:00        1.50   
15  10/4/2018   6:00:00   0      NaN 2018-04-10 06:00:00        0.00   
16  10/4/2018   7:00:00   0      NaN 2018-04-10 07:00:00        1.00   
17  10/4/2018   8:00:00   5        0 2018-04-10 08:00:00        0.00   
18  10/4/2018   9:00:00   7        0 2018-04-10 09:00:00        1.00   
19  10/4/2018  11:00:00   5      3hr 2018-04-10 11:00:00        0.00   
20  10/4/2018  12:00:00   5      4hr 2018-04-10 12:00:00        0.00   
21  10/4/2018  13:00:00   5      5hr 2018-04-10 13:00:00        0.00   
22  10/4/2018  16:00:00   0      NaN 2018-04-10 16:00:00        3.00   
23  10/4/2018  17:00:00   0      NaN 2018-04-10 17:00:00        1.00   
24  10/4/2018  18:00:00   7     11hr 2018-04-10 18:00:00        1.00   

    Expected 7  
0          NaN  
1          NaN  
2          NaN  
3         0.00  
4         1.00  
5         1.00  
6         1.00  
7         1.75  
8         1.25  
9         1.00  
10        1.00  
11        1.00  
12        1.00  
13        1.00  
14        0.00  
15        0.00  
16        1.00  
17        1.00  
18        0.00  
19        2.00  
20        1.00  
21        1.00  
22        3.00  
23        1.00  
24        0.00
```

Comment: Hay Thank you very much. Your answers are great. I have one question here two columns are mentioned expected 5 and 7 . Can I put that values as named column like df['time_diff_5] , and df ['time_diff_7] like this

Comment: @team - sure, just change `df['Expected {}'.format(x)]` like need `df['time_diff_{}'.format(x)]`

Comment: Sorry I have a another question that Can I put these two columns values in one column?

Comment: @team - hmmm, what should be in last value of column?

Comment: Ya It's hard . I am just asking thank you very much.

Comment: @team - because there should be sum or similar of all new columns, but not sure if need it.

Comment: Sorry I have another question , here expected 5 value is containing 0 value from starting time , can we added expected 7 value for that 0 values, if expected 7 is having 0 value add expected 5 value and put it one column?

Comment: @team - Not sure if understand, is possible see like are output data in this new columns and then how looks sum column?

Comment: @hmm actually I am trying to build new sum  equation with this time different and get new value of these two columns into one column. But I got an error due to these two time different values. That's why I am stuck with that.

Comment: @team - I am lost, sorry ;(

Comment: No no its okay you helped me a lot with these amazing code. I found another way  Thank you very much.